# Convert RGB565 to YUV420 / NV21

Tags: android, image-processing, rgb, yuv

I have bitmap in RGB565 format I want to convert it to YUV420/NV21

I found this here

[How to convert RGB565 to YUV420SP faster on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025621/how-to-convert-rgb565-to-yuv420sp-faster-on-android)

but it does not have respective JNI call written there to be used in android code any clean java code for same if some one know ?

Comment: this may heps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960247/convert-bitmap-array-to-yuv-ycbcr-nv21

Comment: It does not accept RGB565 as input to it it does only ARGB888 format.